# Probation period extended

Tags: united-kingdom, probation, contract-extension, food-industry

I started my job in April 8th 2018, so now it's been 3 months. My manager wants to extend this probation another 3 months, which I understand (but I don't agree)
The thing is I haven't signed any contract since I started in April. So I've been working 3 months without a contract and I don't know if this extension is a condition that could happen.

I'm having a meeting next Saturday with manager and boss to discuss about it.

What can I do to "fight" against this extension of my probation? I mean, I don't have a contract at all.
Maybe this could be a condition in it but I cannot know. Something like "if you can't reach the expected level of blah blah, you're probation period would we extended" I don't know if I'm making this more clear or what. Sorry. English isn't my first language.

This is a little company. It's my job place in North Kent and another location in London. Food establishment.

Comment: I don't think this is a legal-advice question.  The author doesn't have a contract and has a disagreement with the supervisor; the question is how to push back.

Answer (score 2):

Without having signed a contract, your leverage is pretty much zero. Even if you did have one, it would almost certainly say "probation may be extended at the sole discretion of the company" or similar so you'd still have zero leverage.

Your best bet is to turn up to the meeting next week, accept the extension in probation, do whatever you can to make your manager happy with your performance but **get a contract to sign** - and make sure it specifies your start date as April; English law recognises that a contract exists if both sides act like one does, even if no physical copy exists.

Comment: I would also suggest getting specific feedback on why the probation is being extended with actionable items on how to get off of probably--possibly even before another 3 months.